# how do i search for certain word in a website?

Tags: search, search-engines

Is there any way to search within a website without manually checking out every link?

Suppose there is some website `www.somewebsite.com` and I want to search for a word in all of the pages `www.somewebsite.com/1`, `www.somewebsite.com/2`, and so on. Is there any way to do it without actually browsing through each and every page?

Comment: Questions about using search engines like Google are off topic for Super User. If you intended to do this in a browser only, please clarify your question—it would be on topic then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Google and type this: site:http://www.somewebsite.com keyword. It will search through the pages they have indexed to find your keyword. This is particularly useful for sites that don't have a search bar.

Have a look at more [Google Tricks](http://lifehacker.com/339474/top-10-obscure-google-search-tricks)

Also, your question isn't very clear are you trying to do this via Shell in Solaris?

Comment: no nothing in particular....i wanted to do it in any possible way,your answer suffices.thanks

Answer (score -1):

Most browsers have a `Find` feature. In IE it's on the `Edit` menu as `Find on this page` or you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>. In Firefox it's the same, but just called `Find` on the menu. Not sure about Chrome.

Whatever browser, it's pretty easy to use to find words.

Comment: but using this i wud have to browse every page and then press ctrl+ F..that wud be really tough..